# How to get device information using Onvif library c#?

Tags: c#, device, windows, onvif

I am making a c# windows application which collects the devices connected to my network using an open source library Onvif.

i am doing in this way.

```
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    var endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://ip_address:port/onvif/device_service");
    var httpBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();            
    var bind = new CustomBinding(httpBinding);
    var temp = new DeviceClient(bind, endPointAddress);
    var request = new GetDeviceInformationRequest();
    var response = temp.GetDeviceInformation(request); ////// Error Here described bellow
    string firm = response.FirmwareVersion;
    string manu = response.Manufacturer;
    string serial = response.SerialNumber;
    string model = response.Model;
```

Error Message :: There was no endpoint listening at http:// something:port/onvif/device_service that could accept the message.this is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action

can any one help me?

I think i am not making proper connection with the server, is it so?
if so then how to resolve it?

Comment: Which open source Onvif library are you using?

Comment: Is "http :// ip_address:port /onvif/device_service" the ListenURI that was returned in the "Hello" or "ProbeMatch" packet?  Not all NVT listen on ".../onvif/device_service".  That is the purpose of the URL, but that exact text is not required.

Comment: Also, you may need to inform your binding of the credentials the NVT requires.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the WS-DISCOVERY gives you extra information. I would try not to use any port after the IP of the camera.

When the test sends an UDP to the multicast address 239.255.255.250, port 3702 (WS-Discovery), this is the camera's answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:d="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery" xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsa:MessageID>uuid:cb3dea50-aa60-11e1-88b9-00408cb972aa</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>uuid:5bca11ff-61b8-4d07-8a26-90274ad51db8</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsa:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ProbeMatches</wsa:Action>
    <d:AppSequence SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true" MessageNumber="1" InstanceId="1338367479"></d:AppSequence>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <d:ProbeMatches>
      <d:ProbeMatch>
        <wsa:EndpointReference>
          <wsa:Address>urn:uuid:65a142fc-a41e-11e1-9cc8-00408cb972aa</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:EndpointReference>
        <d:Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter</d:Types>
        <d:Scopes>
            onvif://www.onvif.org/type/video_encoder 
            onvif://www.onvif.org/type/ptz 
            onvif://www.onvif.org/hardware/P5534-E 
            onvif://www.onvif.org/name/AXIS%20P5534-E 
            onvif://www.onvif.org/location/ 
        </d:Scopes>
        <d:XAddrs>
            h##p://zeroconfIP/onvif/device_service 
            h##p://unicastIP/onvif/device_service
        </d:XAddrs>
        <d:MetadataVersion>1</d:MetadataVersion>
      </d:ProbeMatch>
    </d:ProbeMatches>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Try to discover the response and see if any XAddrs is not the default you expect.

Comment: :: yes, i have tried it on ODM but it also returns me the same error i have mentioned here.

Comment: Sorry, the request must be sent to device_service.

Comment: In particular, the XAddr for device_service is for 99% of all NVT going to be .../onvif/device_service but it _may_ by anything.  It behooves to check the ProbeMatch (or Hello) and use that, rather then calculate it in code.  Based on your comment above, I presume your NVT always does choose .../onvif/device_service.  Try pasting that URL into your browser.  You should see a sane response.  Also try SoapUI to verify your NVT is behaving properly.

Answer (score -1):

Foscam FI9805E soap response on ONVIF GetCapabilities

-

-

```
-<tds:GetCapabilitiesResponse>


  -<tds:Capabilities xsi:type="tt:Capabilities">


    -<tt:Analytics xsi:type="tt:AnalyticsCapabilities">

      <tt:XAddr>http://192.168.1.210:8888/onvif/device_service</tt:XAddr>

      <tt:RuleSupport>true</tt:RuleSupport>

      <tt:AnalyticsModuleSupport>true</tt:AnalyticsModuleSupport>

    </tt:Analytics>


    -<tt:Device xsi:type="tt:DeviceCapabilities">

      <tt:XAddr>http://192.168.1.210:8888/onvif/device_service</tt:XAddr>


      -<tt:Network xsi:type="tt:NetworkCapabilities">

        <tt:IPFilter>false</tt:IPFilter>

        <tt:DynDNS>true</tt:DynDNS>

      </tt:Network>


      -<tt:System xsi:type="tt:SystemCapabilities">

        <tt:DiscoveryResolve>true</tt:DiscoveryResolve>

        <tt:DiscoveryBye>true</tt:DiscoveryBye>

        <tt:RemoteDiscovery>false</tt:RemoteDiscovery>

        <tt:SystemBackup>true</tt:SystemBackup>

        <tt:SystemLogging>true</tt:SystemLogging>

        <tt:FirmwareUpgrade>true</tt:FirmwareUpgrade>


        -<tt:SupportedVersions xsi:type="tt:OnvifVersion">

          <tt:Major>2</tt:Major>

          <tt:Minor>21</tt:Minor>

        </tt:SupportedVersions>

      </tt:System>


      -<tt:Security xsi:type="tt:SecurityCapabilities">

        <tt:TLS1.1>false</tt:TLS1.1>

        <tt:TLS1.2>false</tt:TLS1.2>

        <tt:OnboardKeyGeneration>false</tt:OnboardKeyGeneration>

        <tt:AccessPolicyConfig>true</tt:AccessPolicyConfig>

        <tt:X.509Token>false</tt:X.509Token>

        <tt:SAMLToken>false</tt:SAMLToken>

        <tt:KerberosToken>false</tt:KerberosToken>

        <tt:RELToken>false</tt:RELToken>

      </tt:Security>

    </tt:Device>


    -<tt:Events xsi:type="tt:EventCapabilities">

      <tt:XAddr>http://192.168.1.210:8888/onvif/device_service</tt:XAddr>

      <tt:WSSubscriptionPolicySupport>false</tt:WSSubscriptionPolicySupport>

      <tt:WSPullPointSupport>true</tt:WSPullPointSupport>

      <tt:WSPausableSubscriptionManagerInterfaceSupport>false</tt:WSPausableSubscriptionManagerInterfaceSupport>

    </tt:Events>


    -<tt:Imaging xsi:type="tt:ImagingCapabilities">

      <tt:XAddr>http://192.168.1.210:8888/onvif/device_service</tt:XAddr>

    </tt:Imaging>


    -<tt:Media xsi:type="tt:MediaCapabilities">

      <tt:XAddr>http://192.168.1.210:8888/onvif/device_service</tt:XAddr>


      -<tt:StreamingCapabilities xsi:type="tt:RealTimeStreamingCapabilities">

        <tt:RTPMulticast>false</tt:RTPMulticast>

        <tt:RTP_TCP>true</tt:RTP_TCP>

        <tt:RTP_RTSP_TCP>true</tt:RTP_RTSP_TCP>

      </tt:StreamingCapabilities>

    </tt:Media>


    -<tt:PTZ xsi:type="tt:PTZCapabilities">

      <tt:XAddr>http://192.168.1.210:8888/onvif/device_service</tt:XAddr>

    </tt:PTZ>


    -<tt:Extension xsi:type="tt:CapabilitiesExtension">


      -<tt:DeviceIO xsi:type="tt:DeviceIOCapabilities">

        <tt:XAddr/>

        <tt:VideoSources>1</tt:VideoSources>

        <tt:VideoOutputs>0</tt:VideoOutputs>

        <tt:AudioSources>1</tt:AudioSources>

        <tt:AudioOutputs>0</tt:AudioOutputs>

        <tt:RelayOutputs>0</tt:RelayOutputs>

      </tt:DeviceIO>

    </tt:Extension>

  </tds:Capabilities>

</tds:GetCapabilitiesResponse>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Could you elaborate your answer? How does it match with the question? See [answer].